# How can I get the LDAP SonarQube plugin jar file?

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

Other plugins have download links on their web pages but this one for some reason is only available on dodgy websites with an out of date version.

I could probably build it from source but ideally I'd like to have an "official" binary rather than rely on my patchy maven skills.

Update: The server is not connected to the internet, that's why I can't use the Marketplace.

Comment: You can use SonarQube (login as admin) for downloading the correct version.

Comment: The machine is not connected to the internet unfortunately. Sorry, should have specified this.

Comment: So if the server isn't connected to the Internet you can't download anything. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I download it on my workstation and copy it over to the server by the local network. When the server isn't conneted to the internet I can't use the marketplace functionality.
Anyway, the question has been duly answered and the answer accepted - case closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download jars from:

- https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-ldap-plugin/
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/ldap/sonar-ldap-plugin/

You can also install the plugin by using [Marketplace](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Marketplace):

[image: ldap plugin]

Comment: The machine is not connected to the internet so no marketplace. Sorry, should have specified this.